# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/news-insert.php on line 140

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am working on a project and am working on a page that should do updates and regular inserts.  I found the code elsewhere and have been modifying it to work on my project.  Anyway I fixed many errors but I keep getting a memory leak at line 140.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
     /*
     Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
     */

     // connect to the database
     include("includes/dbconnect.inc.php");

     // creates the new/edit record form
     // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
     function renderForm($title = '', $summary ='', $entry = '', $error = '', $id = '')
     { ?>
     <?php 
     include("includes/header.inc.php");
     ?>
     <body>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <img src="images/zombie_minions.png"/> <!--  Logo  -->
     </td>
     <td>
     <div id="nav"><ul>
     <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><a  class="active"  href="news-insert.php">New/Update News Entry</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/">Admin Panel</a></li>
     <li><a href="/staff/">Staff Admin Panel</a></li>
     <li><a href="/client/">Client Panel</a></li>
     <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
     </ul></div>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <?php
     include("includes/calendar.inc.php");
     ?>
     <td>
     <h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
     <?php if ($error != '') {
echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
. "</div>";
     } ?>

     <form action="" method="post">
       <h2><strong>Edit News Item:</strong></h2><br><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
       <p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
      <!-- Date:<br>
       <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/><br>  -->
       Post Title:<br>
       <input type="text" name="title" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" required /><br>
       Post Summary:<br>
       <input type="text" name="summary" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $summary; ?>" required /><br>
       Post Entry:<br>
       <textarea type="text" name="entry" rows="4" cols="50" min="0" max="650" value="<?php echo $entry; ?>" required /></textarea><br>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
     </form>

     <?php }



     /*

     EDIT RECORD

     */
     // if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
     if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
     // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
     if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
     {
     // get variables from the URL/form
     $id = $_POST['ID'];
     $title = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
     $summary = htmlentities($_POST['summary'], ENT_QUOTES);
     $entry = htmlentities($_POST['entry'], ENT_QUOTES);
     //$date=date('y.m.d h:i:s');

     // check that title and summary are both not empty
     if ($title == '' || $summary == '' || $entry == '')
     {
     // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
     renderForm($title, $summary, $entry, $error, $id);
     }
     else
     {
     // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
     if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET title = ?, summary = ?, entry - ?
     WHERE id=?"))
     {
     $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $title, $summary, $entry, $id);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
     }
     // show an error message if the query has an error
     else
     {
     echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
     }

     // redirect the user once the form is updated
     header("Location: news.php");
     }
     }
     // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
     else
     {
     echo "Error!";
     }
     }
     // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
     else
     {
     // make sure the 'id' value is valid
     if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
     {
     // get 'id' from URL
     $id = $_GET['id'];

     // get the recod from the database
     if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, title, summary, entry FROM news WHERE ID=?"))
     {
     $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
     $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $summary, $entry);
     $stmt->fetch();

     // show the form
     renderForm($title, $summary, $entry, NULL, $id);

     $stmt->close();
     }
     // show an error if the query has an error
     else
     {
     echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
     }
     }
     // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the news.php page
     else
     {
     header("Location: news.php");
     }
     }
     }



     /*

     NEW RECORD

     */
     // if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
     else
     {
     // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     // get the form data
     $title = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
     $summary = htmlentities($_POST['summary'], ENT_QUOTES);
     $entry = htmlentities($_POST['entry'], ENT_QUOTES);

     // check that title and summary are both not empty
     if ($title == '' || $summary == '' || $entry == '')
     {
     // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
     renderForm($title, $summary, $entry, $error);
     }
     else
     {
     // insert the new record into the database
     if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT news (title, summary, entry) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
     {
     $stmt->bind_param("sss", $title, $summary, $entry);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
     }
     // show an error if the query has an error
     else
     {
     echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
     }

     // redirect the user
     header("Location: news.php");
    }

     }
     // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
     else
     {
     renderForm();
     }
     }

     // close the mysqli connection
     $conn->close();
     ?>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <?php
     include("includes/footer.inc.php"); 
     ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your code into to your question. If you add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line, it will maintain its formatting.

Comment: 1,2,3,4, sorry i give up whats line 140?

Comment: Line 140 is this line:

'code' $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $summary, $entry);

Its in the Edit Record section and it is after the update line.

Comment: I added it to pastebin someone else edited it.  I put it on pastebin cause it shows the lines.  What you see is how its formatted on my notepad ++

Do you seriously want me to add 4 spaces to over 200 lines?

Comment: I added the four spaces.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Small mistakes can lead to huge problems....

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, title, summary, entry FROM news WHERE ID=?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); // <-- this is the problem
    $stmt->execute();
```

You don't bind anything to the `?` parameter so it tries to select the entire table. Correct alternatives are:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, title, summary, entry FROM news WHERE ID=:id")
$stmt->bind_param(":id", $id);
```

or

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, title, summary, entry FROM news WHERE ID=?")
$stmt->bind_param(1, $id);
```

Comment: using the 1 in place of the i causes another error and it still leaks memory.  However :id causes Error: could not prepare SQL statement

Comment: Be sure to correct all your statements... I see several in there, all wrong.

Comment: I supposed it would have helped if I explained that I have some experience with php but for the most part I am a newbie.  Plus I have been staring and trying to figure out what I did wrong for close to two weeks now.  LOL  So your statement to find and correct all my statements is not necessarily helpful.    :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase your memory_limit in your php.ini. By default set 128MB.

Comment: I did try that and no matter what size I put it uses it all up.

Comment: if that case, please see your memory usage.. if there enough memory to serve your php... read this, could be help [link](https://www.airpair.com/php/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size)

Comment: You should read a bit better before you answer. The question itself already indicates that limit was set to 500mb so the OP obviously knows where to find that option.

Comment: I tried a number of upper limits and lower limits and it really did not matter what the limit was.  But as Blizz kindly pointed out it seems I failed at the binding part so it was trying to select the whole table not that the table is that big.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your `entry` column isn't longtext. I changed mine from longtext to mediumtext and it solved this same issue.

MySQL v5.6.33